# random background-image on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

I'm trying to have my background image to chance every time a user visits the website. I found some code here on stackoverflow but I can't seem to get it to work.

What is wrong with this code?

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var bgArray = ['A-VOLTE.jpg', 'AL-DI-LA.jpg', 'CON-TE.jpg', 'DAVIDE-E-GOLIA.jpg', 'DELLE-VERITA.jpg', 'DI-NOI.jpg', 'DIVIDERE.jpg', 'FA-NIENTE.jpg', 'FORSE.jpg', 'GRAZIE.jpg', 'IL-CONTATTO.jpg', 'IL-PONTE.jpg', 'IMPERATIVO.jpg', 'INDELEBILE.jpg', '-VOLONTA.jpg', 'MERITAVI.jpg', 'MUOVERE.jpg', 'NEL-DUBBIO.jpg', 'NESSUNO.jpg', 'NON-LO-SAI.jpg', 'PER-DIMENTICARE.jpg', 'PRIMA-DI-ANDARE.jpg', 'PROFONDO.jpg', 'SARA-SUO.jpg', 'SEMPRE.jpg', 'TUTTO-DA-RIFARE.jpg', 'TUTTO-PER-TE.jpg', 'UN-RICORDO.jpg', 'UNTITLED-1.jpg', 'UNTITLED-2.jpg', 'VERO.jpg', 'VIENI-CON-ME.jpg'];
    var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.lenght)];
    // If you have defined a path for the images
    var path = 'artworks/abstract/';
    var imageUrl = path + bg;
    // then you can put it right before the variable 'bg'
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl +')');          
});
```

---

I get no alerts, no bg chance, no nothing.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have miss-spelled, `bgArray.lenght` is wrong. This must be `bgArray.length`

It runs okay!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bgArray = ['A-VOLTE.jpg', 'AL-DI-LA.jpg', 'CON-TE.jpg', 'DAVIDE-E-GOLIA.jpg', 'DELLE-VERITA.jpg', 'DI-NOI.jpg', 'DIVIDERE.jpg', 'FA-NIENTE.jpg', 'FORSE.jpg', 'GRAZIE.jpg', 'IL-CONTATTO.jpg', 'IL-PONTE.jpg', 'IMPERATIVO.jpg', 'INDELEBILE.jpg', '-VOLONTA.jpg', 'MERITAVI.jpg', 'MUOVERE.jpg', 'NEL-DUBBIO.jpg', 'NESSUNO.jpg', 'NON-LO-SAI.jpg', 'PER-DIMENTICARE.jpg', 'PRIMA-DI-ANDARE.jpg', 'PROFONDO.jpg', 'SARA-SUO.jpg', 'SEMPRE.jpg', 'TUTTO-DA-RIFARE.jpg', 'TUTTO-PER-TE.jpg', 'UN-RICORDO.jpg', 'UNTITLED-1.jpg', 'UNTITLED-2.jpg', 'VERO.jpg', 'VIENI-CON-ME.jpg'];
  var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];
  var path = 'artworks/abstract/';
  var imageUrl = path + bg;
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl +')');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

`length` is mispelled in `var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.lenght)];`

Edit: Make sure to work with the javascript console, if that's not already the case. A simple log of `imageUrl` variable would have gave you a clue about the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are randomized the number for the array says lenght  and should be length.

Answer (score 1):

While randomizing, you missed the spelling technique! You must use the words provided.

```
Math.random() * bgArray.lenght
```

Would be:

```
Math.random() * bgArray.length // note the length
```

So, your code would look like:

```
var bg = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];
```

And so on.